# Не хочет запускаться скомпилированный файл в фонов процессе

Tags: golang

Есть обычная программа которая посылает бесконечное количество запросов на сервер работает на горутинах (2) Код с горутинами.

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        go Http()
    }

    var s string 
    fmt.Scanln(&s)

}

func Http() {
    req, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERR")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(req.Header)
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()
}
```

Скомпилирована 64 бита:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
go build get.go
```

Все отлично работает!
Даже с дополнительными горутинами!

Если же я попытаюсь скомпилировать программу с `-H=windowsgui`, то есть моя программа будет выполняться в фоновом процессе то она запуститься если в коде не будет создания доп горутин.

```
set GOARCH=amd64
go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui
```

А если в коде будет создание дополнительных горутин то у меня программа просто напросто не запуститься. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Программа то у вас запускается, но вот при сборке с -H=windowsgui дескрипторы стандартных потоков ввода/вывода закрыты и недоступны для использования.
fmt.Scanln не блокирует выполнение, сразу возвращая ошибку "read /dev/stdin: The handle is invalid", после чего main успешно завершается.
Блокируете выполнение main-горутины каким нибудь иным способом, без использования стандартных потоков.

Comment: Что мне нужно сделать чтоб обойти блокировку?

Comment: Ну например создайте канал и читайте из него сообщения от других горутин.
Когда все горутины сообщат по этому каналу о своём завершении, то выходите из main.